# XML to CSV with all children on one row

Tags: xslt

How can I export the following XML to CSV and have the children on the same row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<NetworkEntity xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns="3.0">
    <Location>
        <SureName>9143146669213334465</SureName>
        <Type>Location</Type>
        <SubType>Rack</SubType>
        <DisplayName>NAME/O2OR_HUIB_04 / O2OR_HUIN_04 - IP DSLAM Type 5 - Model B</DisplayName>
        <Category>INFRASTRUCTURE</Category>
        <Features>
            <Feature>
                <Name>Site</Name>
                <Value>NAME</Value>
                <DisplayName>Site</DisplayName>
                <Discovered>true</Discovered>
            </Feature>
        </Features>
        <Associations>
            <Association>
                <Target xsi:type="Location">
                    <SureName>9143101104413609244</SureName>
                </Target>
                <Type>
                    <Type>ASSOCIATES_WITH</Type>
                </Type>
            </Association>
        </Associations>
    </Location>
</NetworkEntity>
```

I managed to export it like this but I'm failing to add the rest:

```
SureName,Type,SubType,DisplayName,Category,Name,Value,Discovered
9143146669213334465,Location,Rack,NAME/O2OR_HUIB_04 / O2OR_HUIN_04 - IP DSLAM Type 5 - Model B,INFRASTRUCTURE,,,
9143147170713655610,Location,Rack,NAME/12PT_HUIB_06 / 12PT_HUIN_06 - IP DSLAM Type 5 - Model B,INFRASTRUCTURE,,,
9143147288813732088,Location,Rack,NAME/74GW_HUIB_04 / 74GW_HUIN_04 - IP DSLAM Type 5 - Model B,INFRASTRUCTURE,,,
9143155460813423214,Location,Rack,NAME/O2HX_HUIB_02 / O2HX_HUIN_02 - IP DSLAM Type 5 - Model B,INFRASTRUCTURE,,,
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" />
<xsl:variable name="delimiter" select="','" />
<!-- define an array containing the fields we are interested in -->

<xsl:variable name="mainAttributesArray">
    <field>SureName</field>
    <field>Type</field>
    <field>SubType</field>
    <field>DisplayName</field>
    <field>Category</field>
    <field>Name</field> 
    <field>Value</field>    
    <field>Discovered</field>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:param name="fields" select="document('')/*/xsl:variable[@name='mainAttributesArray']/*" />

<xsl:template match="/">
  <!-- output the header row -->
  <xsl:for-each select="$fields">
    <xsl:if test="position() != 1">
      <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
  </xsl:for-each>
  <!-- output newline -->
  <xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
  <xsl:apply-templates select=".//NetworkEntity/Location"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Location">
  <xsl:variable name="currNode" select="." />
  <!-- output the data row -->
  <!-- loop over the field names and find the value of each one in the xml -->
  <xsl:for-each select="$fields">
    <xsl:if test="position() != 1">
      <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="$currNode/*[name() = current()]" />
    <xsl:for-each select="Features/Feature">
    <xsl:text>test</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
    </xsl:for-each>

  </xsl:for-each>
<!-- output newline -->
  <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected outcome:

```
SureName,Type,SubType,DisplayName,Category,Name,Value,Discovered,AssociationTarget,AssociationSureName,AssociationType
9143146669213334465,Location,Rack,NAME/O2OR_HUIB_04 / O2OR_HUIN_04 - IP DSLAM Type 5 - Model B,INFRASTRUCTURE,Site,NAME,Site,True,Location,9143101104413609244,ASSOCIATES_WITH
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could we see the expected result of transforming the example input? Also, please post your current XSLT so we can fix it, instead of having to write your code for you from scratch.

Comment: Added XSLT and expected outcome. Thanks

Comment: You will never go into the Features/Feature for each because the for-each that contains it will skip the Features element altogether.  Therefore the Features/Feature will never be matched/found. You will either need to include Features in your list of fields, or deal with the nested elements outside of the for-each on $fields.

Comment: It seems to me your expected outcome has more fields in the body than it has in the header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you do simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="/NetworkEntity">
    <!-- header (Location + Features + Associations) -->
    <xsl:text>SureName,Type,SubType,DisplayName,Category,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>Name,Value,Discovered,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>AssociationTarget,AssociationSureName,AssociationType&#10;</xsl:text>
    <!-- data -->
    <xsl:for-each select="Location">
        <!-- Location -->
        <xsl:value-of select="SureName"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="Type"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="SubType"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="DisplayName"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="Category"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <!-- Features -->       
        <xsl:value-of select="Features/Feature/Name"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="Features/Feature/Value"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="Features/Feature/Discovered"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <!-- Associations -->
        <xsl:value-of select="Associations/Association/Target/@xsi:type"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="Associations/Association/Target/SureName"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="Associations/Association/Type/Type"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Note that we are assuming here that each `Location` will have no more than one `Feature` and one `Association` - but the structure of your XML allows for multiple instances of each.

Comment: I can use this but I wanted to have a more dynamic approach. This way I will have to write the same piece of code multiple times because I will have to process several XML's. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: It is difficult to have a "dynamic" approach when (a) you have several elements with the same name, (b) at least one of the fields gets its value from an attribute (and this attribute is in a namespace!)